# connect() failed: Connection refused Error for receiving 1MB data from two nodes simultaneously

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, tcp, network-programming

I have a tree structure in which parent sends data to two nodes and children send back the same data to parent. Sending to both children is done using two threads and both the children are getting the message. Parent waits for children to send the message back and spawns a thread for each connection. If my data is less than 1MB, both my children get the data and they send it back to parent, parent gets data from both the children. But when data is 1MB or more, I get `connect() failed: Connection refused` error on one of the child, parent receives data from one child and keeps waiting for other child to send data.

This is the method which spawns new thread on each connection.

```
void Node::listenForMultipleReplies(int portNum, int numOfChildren){
    std::thread threadA[numOfChildren];
    TCPStream* stream = NULL;
    TCPAcceptor* acceptor = new TCPAcceptor(portNum);
    if (acceptor->start() == 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < numOfChildren; ++i){
                    LOG(INFO) << "Listening for input on port: " << portNum;
                    stream = acceptor->accept(); //Blocking; wait till it gets the connection
                    if (stream != NULL) {
                            LOG(INFO) << "Connection Successful";
                            threadA[i] = std::thread(multiple, stream);
                    }
            }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < numOfChildren; i++)
    {
            threadA[i].join();
            LOG(INFO) << "Joined "<< i+1 << "threads successfully!!";
    }
```

}

This is connection_handler which is called by new thread

```
void multiple(TCPStream* stream){
    std::string received;
    ssize_t len;
    char line[HUNDMB];
    LOG(INFO) << "Thread created with ID: " << std::this_thread::get_id();
    if ((len = stream->receive(line, sizeof(line))) > 0) {
            line[len] = 0;
            received = string(line);
            LOG(INFO) << "Results for Query " << received.substr(0,36) << " received; size of the result is "<< received.size();
    }
```

}

Comment: I sincerely hope `HUNDMB` doesn't stand for what I think it does.

Comment: Its a #define, it means 100MB.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought. If your activation stack management on your platform can handle that, I'm impressed.

Comment: Stack space on most platforms is typically way, way less than 100mb. Are you certain that your processes are not crashing and burning, due to immediate stack exhaustion?

Comment: I am not getting run-time error for that. Thanks for pointing it out though. I would initialize that array on heap.

Comment: While you're doing that, sprinkle some additional debug statements, so you can see exactly what each process is doing. You do not appear to be using the stock POSIX socket API, but rather a custom library.

Comment: I am using POSIX socket apis; its just that I have some wrapper on top of that. But even with the regular way of developing a multi-threaded server e.g. http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/unices/116977/ is giving me the exact same error. My function calls are in sync with the calls in the link. And it works. It works normally for data < 1MB.

Comment: @wtpoo `line[len] = 0; received = string(line);`  -- This will not give you the correct results if `line` contains binary data.  In addition, you're altering the data sent back to you when you stick a 0 there.  Don't do it.  This should be `received = string(line, len);` without altering the contents of `line`.